# What is the best practices to handle routes with similar actions?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a picture gallery web application. It has many access routes, they all should render a gallery the same way, the only difference is the order of the pictures.

so for example:

```
mysite.com/favorites -> shows all the pics ordered by number of favorites
mysite.com/views -> shows all the pics ordered by number of views
mysite.com/date -> shows all the pics ordered by date
mysite.com/votes -> shows all the pics ordered by votes
```

Being all these actions so similar between them, Is it a good practice to define one action per route on the controller and pass the order as parameter? Or this logic should be handled in the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If actions are so similar that differ from a parameter, it could make senss to have *one* action that accept that parameter. That last is not a rule, just a preference.

In your specific case you can handle it as follows by using one route with parameter:

```php
Route::get('{orderBy}', 'GalleryController@showPics')
```

Then in your controller you will have something as follows:

```php
class GalleryController extends BaseController
{
    public function showPics($orderBy)
    {
        $pics = $this->service->getPics($orderBy);
        return View::make('gallery')->with('pics', $pics);
    }
}
```

Though it will work fine, there is some points to consider:

1. It is more **semantic** to have controller with specialized action i.e.: *showFavorites*, *showMostViewed*, *showRecents*, *showMostVoted*.
2. Think about **the view**. If you plan to deliver different view, different nested child with different data set, it is better to have an action for each case.
3. **Code readability**. Imagine the controller with several if statements, several return statements, all wrapped in a big try-catch block that have multiple catch clauses... If you can avoid a brain lapse to the next programmer with a spaghetti code, consider it.